# MATLAB calling cuda GPU code without kernel functions

Tags: gpu

As the title indicates. I have C-mex code, which I can successfully call from MATLAB. Now I simply change the suffix from *.cpp into *.cu, and compile with command

```
mexcuda updateElectricFields.cu
```

Compiling and running is successful and yielded the correct results. My question is, is this *.cu file executed on GPU? is the GPU trying to access CPU memory causing slower performance than CPU?

Comment: Are you *observing* slower execution time?

Comment: Yes, but it may have to do with "#pragma omp parallel sections" inside the *.cu file which probably does not take effect when compiled with mexcuda.

Comment: mex and mexcuda are only thin wrappers around calling the compilers directly. If you include mex.h (only) in the parts of your code, where you call mex interface functions, import the libmx.lib and the libmex.lib and depending on the matlab-version set the MATLAB_MEXCMD_RELEASE symbol, you will be fine without mex and mexcuda. Regardless of how you compile it: Cuda code on the GPU is only executed, when you call a kernel, and memory is only copied, if you do so in the program. There is 'nothing' magic mexcuda does. It just supports creating and forwarding compile flags for the Cuda compilation

Comment: I would guess if you just renamed cpp to cu, nothing is done or run on GPU at all. If the new program is slower, probably the optimizer settings have changed as the mexcuda calls nvcc, which calls your native compiler for non-Cuda code parts in your cu file; and at each step the correct compile flags have to be forwarded.